# IHtmlLocalizer with embedded href

Tags: razor, hyperlink

I am trying to embed a link in a localized string for display on a view.  So far what I have will work in en-US, but when I change the default language to Turkish the text displayed does not contain a useful link nor are most string substitutions made.

The IHtmlLocalizer syntax that works for en-US is

@Localizer["Click {0} to return to the {1} application.", @Html.Raw(@String.Format("{0}", @Localizer["here"].Value, @Model.PostLogoutRedirectUri)), @Model.ClientName].Value

Producing "Click here to return to the named applicatio."  With here being a function link.

When I change to Turkish I get the following results.  "{1} uygulamasına geri dönmek için <a href=\"{2}\">{0}</a> tıklayın."

```
@model LoggedOutViewModel
@using CompanyName.Server
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization
@inject IHtmlLocalizer<SharedResources> Localizer

<div class="page-header logged-out">
    @if (Model.PostLogoutRedirectUri != null)
    {
    <div>

        @Localizer["Click {0} to return to the {1} application.", @Html.Raw(@String.Format("<a href=\"{1}\">{0}</a>", @Localizer["here"].Value, @Model.PostLogoutRedirectUri)), @Model.ClientName].Value

    </div>
    }
</div>
}
```

Expected results
"named uygulamasına geri dönmek için İşte tıklayın."
with the word İşte being a valid link.

Actual results
"{1} uygulamasına geri dönmek için <a href=\"{2}\">{0}</a> tıklayın."

Comment: Should have been
@Localizer["Click {0} to return to the {1} application.", @Html.Raw(@String.Format("<a href=\"{1}\">{0}</a>", @Localizer["here"].Value, @Model.PostLogoutRedirectUri)), @Model.ClientName].Value

Comment: This resolved my problem.

@Html.Raw(@Localizer.GetString("Click {0} to return to the {1} application.", @Html.Raw(@String.Format("<a href=\"{0}\">{1}</a>", @Model.PostLogoutRedirectUri, @Localizer["here"].Value)), @Model.ClientName))